# Differences of using ThemeExtension vs class with static theme

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-theme

Flutter 3 is out and I've been experimenting a little.

I have used the `ThemeExtension`

**yt ref:** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8-szcYzFVao

**api ref:** https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/extensions.html

and its great. However I'm starting to realize and ask myself I could have done the same result if I created a class with `static const` as properties such as colors, textstyles or any related theming.

Can someone enlighten me if why I should use `ThemeExtensions` instead?

Static class way:

```dart
// Setup
class AppColors {
  static const primaryColor = Color(0xFFFFFF);
  static const secondaryColor = Color(0xFFFFFF);
}


// Use case inside build

return Container(
  child: Text('Hello world'),
  color: AppColors.primaryColor,
)
```

ThemeExtension Way

```dart
// Setup
class AppColors extends ThemeExtension<AppColors>{
  final Color primaryColor;
  final Color secondaryColor;

  AppColors(this.primaryColor, this.secondaryColor);

  // .
  // ..
  // ... some @overrides such as copyWith() and lerp()
}


// Use case inside build

final colors = Theme.of(context).extensions<AppColors>()!;

return Container(
  child: Text('Hello world'),
  color: colors.primaryColor,
)
```

As you can see here setting up for `ThemeExtension` is quite huge compared on using just the static classes for theme to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `Theme` and/or `ThemeExtension` because:

- You can use Theme(and ThemeExtension) in order to get widgets reactive. If some value is changed(color, text style, etc...), it will notify all listeners and the `build` method of dependent widgets will be dispatched.
- If you change the `themeMode` to dark/light, all application will react to update widgets that are using the theme.
- You can get scoped theme, so if you need some widgets or screen to use a different theme from the entire application, it will be possible too.
- You can share you `ThemeData` between multiple apps and his use will looks like very similar in all apps
- Theme is a good choice to keep a consistent visual pattern
- The child/children widgets just need to know the Theme, as a Single source of truth. If you need to change all screens button's color of the entire app, you will be safe and happy to do that in a single place :)
- You don't need to use `ThemeExtension` to get all these mentioned benefits, but if you do, it will make simpler to keep a very good documented Design System as code.

Comment: Just to add why I accepted this answer. I continued working on the `ThemeExtension` as we have a standard branding. It was a breeze to use especially when we have pre-made custom widgets (according to mockups) that uses this. Made things easier implement colors and all.